# Captcha in zen cart

Tags: php, zen-cart

I am new in zen cart. I am trying to add captcha functionality on registration page. I am using Zen Cart® Versions v1.5.0. I have used CAPTCHA Anti-Robot Registration module which is available on http://www.zen-cart.com site. But still captcha image is not getting display. Is there any backEnd setting required which I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

there is a plugin for the recapcha noted here:

https://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1455:

from the admin side, one would need to enter the sitekey and secret which one would acquire at:  https://www.google.com/recaptcha/admin

Comment: Note that this is not actually included in Zen Cart 1.5.4; you have installed a mod.

Answer (score 0):

Dr. Byte from the Zen Cart core team created a mod which adds CAPTCHA to the registration and contact_us pages.  It works very well and is easy to install.

https://www.zen-cart.com/downloads.php?do=file&id=1455